# ExtJs 4 Panel with XTemplate does not work with IE 8

Tags: extjs

This problem bugs me for a while, I am trying to use the panel with template to display some data. The panel is within a panel, the code is like:

```
Ext.define('foo.bar.MainPanel', {
    extend: 'Ext.panel.Panel',
    ...
    items: [
        xtype: 'panel',
        title: 'Sub panel',
        tpl: 'Hello {name}'
    ]
})
```

The parameter name is passed by loading the store from controller. **e.g. 'Hello Mike' can be displayed correctly on Chrome and FireFox, but display nothing on IE 8** (yes, IE 8, I know it sucks, but have to use it)

Ideas? Any thoughts will be appreciated.

**Update :**

I used

```
item.update(store) // item is the dom object, store is loaded from db
```

in controller side. It works for chrome and firefox, but not IE 8.

I removed that line, and get all items which have xtemplate, then update with store instead, it works.

Not sure why..

Comment: The version of ExtJs is 4.2.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me get this straight: **This is not a problem between IE8 and the code snippet you showed to us.**

I copied your code snippet into our standard ExtJS HTML file, added the required data and put the panel into a viewport:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge">
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/vnd.microsoft.icon" href="../favicon.ico">
    <title>Test</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="resources/css/gray.css">
    <script id="microloader" type="text/javascript" src="ext/ext-all-debug.js"></script>
    <script>
        Ext.onReady(function() {
            Ext.define('foo.bar.MainPanel', {
                xtype:'x',
                extend: 'Ext.panel.Panel',
                items: [{
                    xtype: 'panel',
                    title: 'Sub panel',
                    tpl: 'Hello {name}',
                    data: {
                        name:'Alexander'
                    }
                }]
            });
            Ext.create('Ext.container.Viewport', {
                items:[{
                    xtype:'x'
                }]
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

The code above gives me "Hello Alexander" in Chrome 37, IE11 and IE8. I would guess that you are doing some IE8-incompatible hokey-pokey in the code you didn't show us.

Have you already tried F12 debugger tools in IE8? Kept a closer look at the console log? Sifted through the element list?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It's weird.
Actually, the panel displayed in a second, then it got disappeard. I used the console to view log, which is exact same as the one Chrome console shows.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue My XTemplate was not working on IE. It was about function that was receiving parameter inside my XTemplate and IE was not dealing with it properly.
By replacing

"{[this.getCompanyDescriptionHTML({values})]}"

with

"{[this.getCompanyDescriptionHTML({values:values})]}"

Resolved my Problem

[ExtJs XTemplate is not working with IE when it contains functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42301039/extjs-xtemplate-is-not-working-with-ie-when-it-contains-functions/42301116#42301116)

Comment: could u please format your code by putting 4 space in front of each of your code lines ?