# ExtJs XTemplate is not working with IE when it contains functions

Tags: internet-explorer, extjs, xtemplate

I am using ExtJs (4.2) I am facing an Issue that my XTemplate is not working with IE when it contains functions.

Anyone can help.

Answer (score 1):

I was not getting more help on this topic then I dig into it and found that apply function is not working perfectly for IE.

```
xTemplate = new Ext.XTemplate(me.getTemplate(), {
            getCompanyDescriptionHTML: me.getCompanyDescriptionHTML
        });
xTemplate.apply(data));
```

What apply method do, it compiles the template and bind data in. 
I further investigated it and found that apply itself is not a problematic. It is function within my template and IE is unable to handle the values passed to the function.

```
getTemplate: function () {
        var tpl = "<tpl>";
        tpl += "<div>";
        tpl += "{[this.getCompanyDescriptionHTML({values})]}";
        tpl += "</div>";
}
```

I tried many tricks and finally replacing function parameter values with values:values solved my problem.

```
"{[this.getCompanyDescriptionHTML({values:values})]}"
```

The good thing is, the same worked for Chrome as well :)

Comment: When you use `{[...]}` in an XTemplate, everything inside is standard javascript. `{values}` is not valid, as braces are used for creating objects, values is already an object so if you want to pass this you can use `{[this.getCompanyDescriptionHTML(values)]}` alternatively you can access its properties to only pass certain values e.g. `{[this.getCompanyDescriptionHTML(values.id,values.name)]}